# タグ ssl と tls について

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

[ssl](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl)と[tls](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tls)に対して何等かの対応が必要に感じます。本来ならTLSを正とすべきですが、本家では[SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssl/synonyms)を正としたタグシノニムを設定しているようです。

---

とりあえず[ssl ← tls](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/ssl/synonyms)を推奨（提案？）してみました。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

問題がなさそうならば、本家に従い、

ssl <- tls

のタグシノニムを設定しようと思っていますが、いかかでしょうか？

---

(追記@2019/03/22)

タグシノニムを設定しました。

Comment: 私も本家に準じることに賛成します。

Comment: 質問より回答の方が評価が低いのはあまり賛同されていないのか心配になります。シノニム推奨にもほとんど投票されていませんでしたし。とはいえ、対案も出ませんでしたし…うーん。

Comment: @sayuri タグシノニムに投票するためには、そのタグに対してある程度の回答投稿のスコアが必要になる様子です。むしろ、投票できる人の方がごく限られているような気がします。また、Meta での投票傾向からすると、7/6 という投票数は、ほぼほぼ賛成である、というのが個人的な認識です。問題がある場合には、解除すれば良いと思うので、ひとまずモデレータ権限で承認を行なった次第です。